# Keep android.text.StaticLayout with Proguard in React Native project

Tags: android, react-native, proguard, android-proguard

I'm building a hybrid React Native and native Android app with 
Proguard enabled.
The build fails with the following warning:

`Warning: com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder.proxy.StaticLayoutProxy: can't find referenced method 'StaticLayout(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int,android.text.TextPaint,int,android.text.Layout$Alignment,android.text.TextDirectionHeuristic,float,float,boolean,android.text.TextUtils$TruncateAt,int,int)' in library class android.text.StaticLayout`

If I add `-dontwarn android.text.StaticLayout` to my proguard config it builds, but then it crashes at runtime, so I believe I should force that constructor to be kept by proguard.

I try this:

```
-keep class android.text.StaticLayout extends android.text.Layout { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class android.text.StaticLayout extends android.text.Layout {
public <init>(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int,android.text.TextPaint,int,android.text.Layout$Alignment,android.text.TextDirectionHeuristic,float,float,boolean,android.text.TextUtils$TruncateAt,int,int);
```

But the build fails with that setup. What would be the correct proguard rule?